# Setting the location of MotionEvent e on the OnTouch method of Android

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a simulation that needs to flip screen coordinates into my simulation coordinates. I do this just fine like this...

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
  e.setLocation(...);
  ...
}
```

That works perfectly well for my first pointer, but I also need to set the location for my second and third pointer when multiple touches are occurring. Does anyone know how to do that? There isn't a method called e.setLocation that accepts the pointerindex, etc...

Comment: Are you using the various `MotionEvent` actions? Could you post some higher fidelity code, please?